# A piece of code cannot be compiled by intel compiler but clang will compile it

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, icc

The following code is a minimum working (or perhaps non-working) example.

What it does is basically encapsulates a bunch of std::map structures as  private members in a base class. To avoid writing a lot of setters and getters, they are implemented as template functions.

```
//  test.cpp

#include <map>
#include <iostream>    

enum class E0
{
    F0, F1, F2,
};
```

The declaration of the base class.

```
using std::map; 
class P_base
{
private:
    map<E0, int> m_imap;
    //  ...
    //  ... Other std::map members with different key types and value types.
public:
    map<E0, int> & imap;    
    //  ...
    //  ... Other std::map references.

    P_base() : imap(m_imap) {}    

    template<typename map_type, typename key_type, typename val_type>
    void set(map_type & m, const key_type & k, const val_type & v)
    {
        m[k] = v;
    }    

    template<typename map_type, typename key_type>
    auto access_to_map(const map_type & m, const key_type & k) -> decltype(m.at(k))
    {
        return m.at(k);
    }
};    

class P : private P_base
{
public:
    decltype(P_base::imap) & imap;    

    P() : P_base(), imap(P_base::imap) {}    

    template<typename map_type, typename key_type, typename val_type>
    void set(map_type & m, const key_type & k, const val_type & v)
    {
        P_base::set(m, k, v);
    }    

    template<typename map_type, typename key_type>
    auto access_to_map(const map_type & m, const key_type & k) -> decltype(P_base::access_to_map(m, k))
    {
        return P_base::access_to_map(m, k);
    }
};
```

main

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;    

    P op;    

    op.set(op.imap, E0::F0, 100);
    op.set(op.imap, E0::F1, 101);
    op.set(op.imap, E0::F2, 102);    

    cout << op.access_to_map(op.imap, E0::F1) << endl;

}


$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out
101
```

But if I compile it with intel compiler (icpc version 15.0.3 (gcc version 5.1.0 compatibility)), the compiler gives me this error message (which I don't undertand at all, especially when clang will compile the code):

```
$ icpc -std=c++ test.cpp && ./a.out
test.cpp(67): error: no instance of function template "P::access_to_map" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (std::__1::map<E0, int, std::__1::less<E0>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const E0, int>>>, E0)
        object type is: P
  cout << op.access_to_map(op.imap, E0::F1) << endl;
```

And it also confuses me by not complaining about the set function.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: g++ rejects the code at the same place, so I guess icc's g++ compatibility mode is working!

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* My answer applies to g++ - hopefully it's the same as icc.

Here is a smaller test case:

```
struct Base
{
    int func(int t) { return t; }
};

struct Der : Base
{
    template<typename T>
    auto f(T t) -> decltype(Base::func(t))
    {
        return t;
    }
};

int main(){ Der d; d.f(5); }
```

The error is:

```
mcv.cc: In function 'int main()':
mcv.cc:16:25: error: no matching function for call to 'Der::f(int)'
 int main(){ Der d; d.f(5); }
                     ^
mcv.cc:16:25: note: candidate is:
mcv.cc:9:7: note: template<class T> decltype (t->Base::func()) Der::f(T)
  auto f(T t) -> decltype(Base::func(t))
   ^
mcv.cc:9:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
mcv.cc: In substitution of 'template<class T> decltype (t->Base::func())     Der::f(T) [with T = int]':
mcv.cc:16:25:   required from here
mcv.cc:9:38: error: cannot call member function 'int Base::func(int)' without object
  auto f(T t) -> decltype(Base::func(t))
```

This can be fixed by changing `decltype(Base::func(t))` to `decltype(this->Base::func(t))`.  A corresponding fix fixes your code sample, for me.

Apparently, the compiler doesn't consider that `Base::func(t)` should be called with `*this` as hidden argument.  I don't know if this is a g++ bug, or if clang is going beyond the call of duty.

Note that in C++14, since the function has a single return statement, the trailing return type can be omitted entirely:

```
template<typename T>
auto f(T t)
{
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it, and I totally agree it is a g++ bug. I tested it on my own laptop with gcc 5.1.0. It passed. The server with icpc installed is running OSX, whose gcc is the xcode version, not a separate installation.